# How to take the backup of objects privileges on all schemas and its assigned roles except default user accounts in oracle?

Tags: oracle, permissions, privileges, sql-grant

Basically On TEST Environment how to take the **backup of privileges** and **to generate grant statement** of all objects owned by users except defaults in oracle before DB refresh from PROD to TEST.

So, we can revert back to those privileges after refresh to avoid any **permission denied** issue.

And also Looking for an alternate Solution of "**dbms_metadata.get_dependent_ddl**" and "**dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl**" package. As it takes lots of time and generates many duplicate statements.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the Grant Code statement script of all schemas except default accounts

```
set long 20000 longchunksize 20000 pagesize 0 linesize 1000 feedback off verify off trimspool on

spool file_name.sql
select 'grant '||granted_role||' to '||grantee||';' from DBA_ROLE_PRIVS where grantee in (SELECT usr.username FROM sys.dba_users usr WHERE usr.created > (SELECT created FROM sys.v_$database))
union all
select 'grant '||privilege||' on '||owner||'.'||table_name||' to '||grantee||';' from DBA_TAB_PRIVS where grantee in (SELECT usr.username FROM sys.dba_users usr WHERE usr.created > (SELECT created FROM sys.v_$database))
union all
select 'grant '||privilege||' to '||grantee||';' from DBA_SYS_PRIVS where grantee in (SELECT usr.username FROM sys.dba_users usr WHERE usr.created > (SELECT created FROM sys.v_$database))
union all
select 'grant '||privilege||' ('||column_name||') '||' on '||owner||'.'||table_name||' to '||grantee||';' from DBA_COL_PRIVS where grantee in (SELECT usr.username FROM sys.dba_users usr WHERE usr.created > (SELECT created FROM sys.v_$database));
spool off
```

To check the List of assigned roles.

```
select granted_role from DBA_ROLE_PRIVS where grantee in (SELECT usr.username FROM sys.dba_users usr WHERE usr.created > (SELECT created FROM sys.v_$database));
```

To generate the grant privileges statement of roles.

```
set long 20000 longchunksize 20000 pagesize 0 linesize 1000 feedback off verify off trimspool on

spool file_name.sql
select 'grant '||privilege||' on '||owner||'.'||table_name||' to '||grantee||';' from DBA_TAB_PRIVS where grantee in (select granted_role from DBA_ROLE_PRIVS where grantee in (SELECT usr.username FROM sys.dba_users usr WHERE usr.created > (SELECT created FROM sys.v_$database)));
spool off
```